# Writing and reading list into a file

Tags: python

I have the following code, what will be the best way to write that list into a file and read it back in the list format as it is. Any help will be appreciated.

```
l=[
            "[ 'ARAJunkyard_Build_Branch' , 7 , 6 , 1 ]",
            "[ 'ARAJunkyard_Build_Head' , 10 , 10 , 0 ]",
            "[ 'ARAJunkyard_DevUnitTests_Branch' , 10 , 9 , 1 ]",
            "[ 'ARAJunkyard_DevUnitTests_HEAD' , 10 , 0 , 10 ]",
            "[ 'ARAJunkyard_Functional_Tests' , 7 , 2 , 5 ]"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `pickle` module, you can store almost any object using `pickle`:

```
import pickle

l=[
            "[ 'ARAJunkyard_Build_Branch' , 7 , 6 , 1 ]",
            "[ 'ARAJunkyard_Build_Head' , 10 , 10 , 0 ]",
            "[ 'ARAJunkyard_DevUnitTests_Branch' , 10 , 9 , 1 ]",
            "[ 'ARAJunkyard_DevUnitTests_HEAD' , 10 , 0 , 10 ]",
            "[ 'ARAJunkyard_Functional_Tests' , 7 , 2 , 5 ]"]

with open("test.dat", "wb") as fp:
    pickle.dump(l, fp)


with open("test.dat", "rb") as fp:
    l2 = pickle.load(fp)

print l2
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html